# How to use && inside echo without using quotes?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to write a command like this inside a file using only cmd.exe (with ShellExecute, C++),

It's something like this:

```
timeout /t 10 && start cmd.exe /C "ssh -o ..."
```

I tried using this:

```
echo timeout /t 10 && start cmd.exe /C "ssh -o ..." > myfile.bat
```

but it cuts when it reaches `&&` and I can't use quotes on the entire string, so what should I do? I don't want to use anything other than cmd.exe, and I just want to write this to a `.bat` file.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Use disappearing quotes.**

```
FOR %%^" in ("") do (
    echo %%~"timeout /t 10 && start cmd.exe /C "ssh -o ..." %%~" > myfile.bat
)
```

**2) Escape the special characters**

```
echo timeout /t 10 ^&^& start cmd.exe /C "ssh -o ..." > myfile.bat
```

**3) Use delayed expansion**

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set "line=timeout /t 10 && start cmd.exe /C "ssh -o ...""
echo !line! > myFile
```